# How do I access and display specific records in a MySQL relational-database using JDBC/Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a project-management-system that used to read data from text-files, but is now being changed to read data from a database.

I am trying to figure out how to display specific information in different tables based on the project number in the projects table.
All of the tables in my database are related to this project table.

#### A Visual Presentation of My Database

ERD for my database:
[image: ERD for my database]

#### My Problem

Neatly display all the information for for project.

What I am trying to figure out is, how do I get a specific record in one table, based on the foreign-keys in my projects table?

For example, if a project has an architect with the architect_name "Bryan" , then how do I display the architect details for just "Bryan"?

#### My Code for my displayAll method

```
public static void viewAllProjects() {

    // Calling the 'connectionAttempt' method to connect to the 'ebookstore' database.
    Connection connection = connectionAttempt();

    PreparedStatement ps;

    // Using a try- catch block to print the data for a specific record in the 'books' table.
    try {
        // Creating and using a normal statement to select the specific record in the database.
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        // SQL select statement
        String q = "select * from architect\n" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select * from contractor\n" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select * from customer" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select * from shopping_basket\n" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select * from projects\n" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select * from building_info";

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(q); // Executing statement

        // Printing ResultSet
        if (rs.next()) {
            String projectDetails = "\nProject Number: " + rs.getString("project_number") + "\n" +
                    "Project Name: " + rs.getString("project_name") + "\n" +
                    "Type of building: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "ERF Number: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Physical Address: " + rs.getString("physical_address") + "\n" +
                    "Total fee charged for project: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Total amount already paid: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Deadline of the project: " + rs.getString("deadline") + "\n" +
                    "Project Finalised: " + rs.getString("finalised") + "\n" +

                    "\nArchitect Name: " + rs.getString("architect_name") + "\n" +
                    "Architect Telephone Number: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +
                    "Architect Email-Address: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +
                    "Architect Physical Address: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +

                    "\nContractor Name: " + rs.getString("contractor_name") + "\n" +
                    "Contractor Telephone Number: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +
                    "Contractor Email-Address: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +
                    "Contractor Physical Address: " + rs.getString("id") + "\n" +

                    "\nCustomer Name: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Customer Telephone Number: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Customer Email-Address: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "Customer Physical Address: " + rs.getString("HERE") + "\n" +
                    "----------------------------------\n";

            System.out.println(projectDetails);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Record Not Found...");
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

My code for the `connectionAttempt` method works, as I used it before.

Please let me know if there are any other details I can provide.

Answer (score 2):

This project is not going to work out until you learn SQL. Once you do, you'd know that UNIONing together every row **in the entire database** is a *crazy* way to work. This attempts to pump over all data in your database in an incredibly inefficient way.

> If a project has an architect with the architect_name "Bryan" , then I how do display the architect details for just "Bryan".

An SQL statement along the lines of `SELECT * FROM architect WHERE architect_name = ?` (make that your `PreparedStatement`), then use `ps.setString(1, "The name of the architect goes here");` to set the query parameters, then run it, and voila.

You may want to 'marshal' the returned data into a specialized java object that represents exactly the data returned, because working with some java class is a lot simpler than having to run a ton of `rs.getString...` style statements. more on that later.

If you want all projects that brian made, then there's no way to tell unless you explain to us how your database is designed. But it'll look something along the lines of:

```
SELECT p.* FROM projects p
  INNER JOIN architect a ON p.architect = a.unid
  WHERE a.architect_name = ?
```

You need to know about SQL - search the web for any SQL tutorial.

You also need to interact with it from the java side. You're currently doing raw JDBC - not recommended. Read up on [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org/) or if you prefer, [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/). These also make that marshalling thing *a lot* simpler.

Comment: I've seen the error of my ways. I was making such simple mistakes. I read through those links you sent me and it helped a lot. Thank you very much for your help. :D